# blockAttacks not working on pragmarx/firewall package for Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, firewall

I tried to use block attacks middleware on all web routes using pragmarx/firewall but it is not blocking the attacks.

I added the \PragmaRX\Firewall\Middleware\BlockAttacks::class on 'web' in $middlewareGroups on App\Http\Kernel.php

```
....
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \PragmaRX\Firewall\Middleware\BlockAttacks::class,
....
```

Then I used Postman's runner and set iteration into 51.
After 50 requests, the request and IP still not blocked.
I also create and run this script

```
var url = 'sample.php';
for (var i = 1; i <= 60; i++) 
{ 
  $.post(url, function (data) { console.log(data); }); 
}
```

but IP still not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/firewall), the `\PragmaRX\Firewall\Middleware\BlockAttacks::class,` entry should be inside `firewall` middleware group and not in `web`.

You should double check if each step of setup is followed as per the documentation and your Laravel version.